# How to stop a click on Combobox in Jtable, from coping the value of previous row selection for a Combobox

Tags: java, swing, combobox, dropdown

I've a swing GUI which displays the content of the Database, and also allows the user to modify it. We've used Jtable to manage the same. A few of the columns have drop down as an option to set the value.

Now the issue is that for all the ComboBox, we are facing an issue. When we selected value for one of the rows for a combobox and later click on another row of the same column. It copies the value of the previous selection. I want to stop this behaviour. How do I stop it ? Which listener might be coping the values ?

Comment: It's impossible to say without some kind of example which demonstrates your problem, but, `TableCellEditor` calls `getTableCellEditorComponent` passing in the current value of the cell before it displays the cell editor, this should be your opportunity to update the combobox as required

Comment: Thank You

Lets take an example that I've a Employee Schema from DB that I'm trying to display using JTable. And I've a ComboBox for updating his Country of residence. So the issue is like when the user clicks on a row number 5 and updates a Country for user A, and then just clicks rows number 10 for users B. At that point the value of Country selected for user A is getting automatically copied to User B's country value. 

I'm playing around with 'getTableCellEditorComponent', But it uses 'getCellEditorValue' to set value, and that's always getting the previous selection values with it.

Comment: Well, without a runnable example which demonstrates your problem, you're only going to get guess work from us

Comment: I understand that it would be very difficult to point out without the code.But I won't be able to do it here. I'll post my finding as soon as I get over this one.

Comment: I've managed to fix the same. It was because of incorrect implementation of the JComboBoxEnacted in our API. Additional reload was getting called which pulled other values.